# Logical form of this statement?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, logic

In logical form, how would you express :

Take any two fractions, add them together, and the result will be an integer

Comment: $\forall x \forall y ((x \in \mathbb{Q} \land y \in \mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow x+y \in \mathbb{Z})$. If you cannot mix arithmetical notation ($+$) with set-theory one ($\in$), you must use predicates $Q$ and $Z$ that hold respectively when $x$ is a rational and $y$ is an integer.

Comment: please put your comment as an answer, and I'd be more than glad to give you the checkmark :)

Comment: Or shorter $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{Q}:x+y\in\mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symbolic expression must be :

> $\forall x \forall y ((x \in \mathbb{Q} \land y \in \mathbb{Q}) \rightarrow x+y \in \mathbb{Z})$.

If you cannot mix arithmetical notation ($+$) with set-theoretic one ($\in$), you must use predicates $Q(x)$  and $Z(z)$ that hold respectively when $x$ is a *rational* and $z$ is an *integer*.

In this case you will have :

> $\forall x \forall y ((Q(x) \land Q(y)) \rightarrow Z(x+y))$.

If you want to avoid the $+$ symbol, you must introduce a *predicate* $S(x,y,z)$ that holds of $x, y$ and $z$ precisely when $x+y=z$. In this case you will have :

> $\forall x \forall y \forall z ((Q(x) \land Q(y) \land S(x,y,z)) \rightarrow Z(z))$

**but** in this case you must prove that :

$\forall x \forall y \forall z \forall w (S(x,y,z) \land S(x,y,w) \rightarrow z = w)$

i.e. you can avoid *functions* using instead *predicates*, but you must ensure that they "behave" correctly.